# Why did we use radius of circle instead of arc length here over time?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, orbital-motion, vectors

In my textbook hcv Verma volume 1 . Page no 102.
It says that in Acceleration in circular motion paragraph that : Heading is Circular motion. All the text is written there. If any confusion , pls let me know.

There is a particle moving in a circle and is at position r on the arc length s.
Now , earlier the text in textbook was that velocity = $\frac{ds}{ dt}$. ( where s is arc length of circle )
But in column of acceleration in circular motion it writes that .

$velocity$ = $\frac{dr}{ dt}$( where r is a position vector ) . Now , they solved the equation like r ( i cos theta + j sin theta ) .

r * omega [ -i sin theta + j cos theta ).

Therefore , my question is that in the  first place that why did they take $\frac{dr}{ dt}$  and not $\frac{ds}{ dt}$?

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two expression for the velocity are equivalent up to a point, and that has to do with scalars and vectors.

The position *along* a circle is given by $$s=R\theta$$ where $\theta$ is the angle with respect to usually the $x$ axis and $R$ is the radius. But you can also write your position on the plane as

$$\textbf{r}=R(cos(\theta), sin(\theta))$$

(in your notation, $ \textbf{r} = \textbf{i} R cos(\theta) + \textbf{j} R sin(\theta)$ - it is an "arrow" starting in the origin and directed towards your position on the circle).

[From now on, I will use parenthesis or bold/hat font for vectors and normal font for scalars.]

Notice they are two different definitions: one is the position along the circle and it is *not* a vector: it's the arc-length.
The second one is the position on the plane and it is a vector. They also have different magnitude: one is the amount of space you travelled along the circle, the second one is its instantaneous position. So $s$ is not the *position vector*, it's a scalar describing how much you travelled "around" the origin.

On the other hand, $\textbf{r}$, unlike what happens in one-directional motion, is not a measure of "space travelled" but only an instantaneous position vector. Hidden in $\textbf{r}$ is the fact that you are *not* moving in the radial direction but you are moving *along* the circle. $s=R\theta$ quantifies that.

Of course, the velocity is the derivative of the position $r$ so
$$\textbf{v}=d\textbf{r}/dt=R( -sin(\theta)d\theta/dt, cos(\theta)d\theta/dt)=R\omega(-sin(\theta), cos(\theta))$$

where $\omega=d\theta/dt$ is the angular velocity. This of course if $R$ is constant.

This is the most general expression for the (vector) velocity. Notice that it is a vector pointing along the tangent of the circle which is the direction of motion. If the radius was not constant, you would have to account for its change in time too so we will neglect it for now.

The magnitude of the velocity thus is $v=|v|=R\omega$. Now because the motion is circular, you can compute *the magnitude* of the velocity from the change of position along the circle, transforming a bi-dimensional problem in a one-dimensional one. So:

$$v=ds/dt=Rd\theta/dt=R\omega$$ and the two expressions are the same (again, at constant $R$). But as you do this, you loose the information of the direction, you have to add it "manually" by saying you are moving along the circle. In other words, this only holds for the magnituded of the velocity, not its vector-part. And velocity *is* a vector!

So in *circular uniform* motion the two expressions are equivalent. But the first one is vectorial in 2D, the second one is a scalar in 1D.

They are connected by the fact that the *space travelled* is the integral of the magnitude of the speed, i.e.

$$s=\int |\textbf{v}| dt = \int R\omega dt = \int Rd\theta=R\theta$$ using
$\omega dt = d\theta$ i.e. the "small" angle change. This is how your expression from $s$ pops up from a vector description as "space travelled" - but to derive general expression we need  a vector form!

So if you take this expression and you write $\textbf{v}=R\omega\hat{t}=ds/dt\hat{\textbf{t}}$ where $\hat{\textbf{t}}$ is a unit tangent vector then you have added the information about the orientation of the vector in your description i.e. you mixed the two descriptions (magnitude is $ds/dt$ but direction is $\hat{\textbf{t}}$) and then you can further operate on this expression, remembering that now you *also* have to do the derivative of $\hat{\textbf{t}}=(-sin(\theta), cos(\theta))$ which changes over time!

Trouble starts if we look at the acceleration. If now you want the acceleration, you have do to the differntiatee again. If you differentiate the first expression (again we use $\omega=d\theta/dt$ where applicable and we have a $t-$-dependency both in $\theta$ and, in principle, in $\omega$.

$$\textbf{a}=d\textbf{v}/dt= R (-d\omega/dt sin(\theta)-\omega^2 cos(\theta), d\omega/dtcos(\theta)-\omega^2 sin(\theta))$$
So we get the vector, calling $d\omega/dt=\alpha$ for the angular acceleration:

$$\textbf{a}=R(\alpha sin(\theta)-\omega^2cos(\theta), \alpha cos(\theta)-\omega^2 sin(\theta))$$

if $\alpha=0$ (uniform motion) you get

$$a=-R\omega^2(cos(\theta), sin(\theta)=\omega^2 \textbf{r}$$ where I highlighted that you recover the position vector $\textbf{r}$ and that the acceleration points in the radial direction. You have an acceleration even though $\alpha=0$ because the velocity vector is changing *direction* over time and not magnitude.

If you use the previous approach, the scalar one

$$a=dv/dt=d(R\omega)/dt = R\alpha=0$$
you loose this information because, in your 1D problem along the circle, the vector is not changing direction so the acceleration is 0. So you can not use it in this case. By using the $s=R\theta$ description, you are only focusing on motion *along* the curve and that part has no acceleration (velocity is always oriented *along* the curve), but you are neglecting the fact that the acceleration vector is also rotating on the plane.

In more specific term, the second scalar approach is describing the system only in terms of the angle $\theta$ i.e. in terms of $\omega$ and $\alpha$ so you are only able to compute components having to do with variation of the angle $\theta(t)$ and are not accounting for the radial change. To "turn" the $s=R\theta$ into a vector, [you need to go to polar coordinates appropriately](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Vector_calculus), because you are missing a component (the radial one) in your description.

Comment: For the first two cases you took for position of a particle on the plane ( s is total distance  and r is for displacement ). Both cases have this thing different in them right ?

Comment: But will their time be same ?

Comment: Q 2 is why why did we not use ds / dt instead of dr /dt?

Comment: Q 3 , can we position along the plane is xz or yz axis ?

Comment: Q4 mod of position vector is radius of circle ?

Comment: I feel like you have some misunderstanding about vectors etc. Maybe read the answer in detail, I included some more connection between $s$ and $r$. Q1: no, $r$ is a vector which rotates periodically, while $s$ increases continously from 0 to $\omega t$ over time. Q2: because $s$ is a scalar *not* a vector and you need to derive vectors in general! Q3: the vector description is a very general description, you can use it in any coordinate system if you are careful with definitions. Q4: yes: that's why you can not differentiate the magnitude - it's constant. You need the full position VECTOR.

Comment: In other terms: if you use s=ds/dt you are only concerned for motion along the circle. If you use the vector you get all components right. Using the first approach leads easily to errors if you forget you are "projecting" your problem in 1D.

Comment: For t cap , you wrote - sin theta , cos theta ? Does , mean + ?

Comment: Q 5 , I didn’t understand what you meant that it is an arrow towards your side ?

Comment: No t is the tangent so it has that minus.  Try drawing the vectors. For Q5 i was referring to the geometrical intepretation of vectors as "arrows"

Comment: I am not getting the radial acceleration part ? How did we get that actually . Form the starting , we say that velocity is always along the direction of motion I.e tangential direction . We didn’t write radial velocity? Then , why to write radial acceleration. Thank you for helping so much

Comment: You will find all these information in a good physics book with drawings explaining. I encourage you do check them! The velocity changes direction. The acceleration is the change in velocity. Draw two tangential velocity vectors. Draw their difference using vector sum. The difference (i.e. the acceleration) will point radially. The derivative of the tangent of a circle is radial. Check the derivation I made in my answer: you get a radial vector at the end. Good luck with your studies!

Comment: Ok right. Can you recommend me some book like that .

Comment: So , it is only the radial direction I am not getting. If you see , we did point position vector but we did not say it as a velocity direction right ? It is just position vector .

Comment: From where did you get - omega ^2 cos theta and - omega ^2 sin theta ??@JalfredP in a = dv/dt

Comment: The point where you recovered the position vector r , why did you not write - sign over there ? Also , I think you should have had written -w^2 sin ^2 theta

Comment: How do you tell that for the acceleration value you got. It is centripetal  or radial ? It Should be tangential but why is it radial in textbook ?@JalfredP

Comment: There might be sign mistakes, but focus on the concept: from the definition of velocity you need the derivative of the position vector. That's what you have to do. Same goes for acceleration. I will fix it as soon as possible. The terms - omega ^2 cos theta  come from the chain rule when differentiating the velocity which depends in principle on time in both the theta and omega terms.

Comment: You solved it real

Comment: Ly well. My doubt is when alpha is not equal to 0 . Then , If you see the text in my textbook. I I didn’t understand the way they differentiated acceleration. Because they also got tangential direction from there. That is not there or I couldn’t see it in your equation . Please help in that also

Comment: If alpha is NOT zero that is not a uniform motion, it's moving faster and faster around the circle so: the acceleration is both tangential (it's accelerating along the circle and the magnitude of the velocity is increasing) and radial (the velocity is also changing direction, not only magnitude)

Comment: I am asking from the text in my textbook right . How did they also write a component of tangential + radial ? You can from the photo . Tangential is dv/dt *et . Where is this value in your text ?@JalfredP

Comment: If alpha is not 0, the term Rdw/dt(-sin(theta), cos(theta)) remains and that is tangential